# How to get random row in object variable in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, object

Sorry for my bad english, I want to get a single row in my object. And I want that in random order. Im using `array_rand()` and it only return errors as stated below:

> ErrorException: array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in file C:\xampp\htdocs\user\TestProject\app\Http\Controllers\TestController.php on line

Here is my object.

```
"my_list": [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "My Name Test",
     "address": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "city": "Manila",
            "country": "Philippines" 
         }
     ]
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Your Name Test",
     "address": [
         {
            "id": 2,
            "city": "Cebu",
            "country": "Philippines",
         }
     ]
   }
]
```

The problem is I want only to get a single row to the `my_list` which is `object` and not an `array`.

Here is my code.

```
$course = Course::where('id', 1)->with('my_list')->first();
$random_list = array_rand($course->my_list);
return $random_list;
```

I also try adding number of row in the `array_rand` like this.

```
$random_list = array_rand($course->my_list, 1);
```

But still not working.

What did I missed?

Comment: Updated my answer. Could you tell me the reason why it's not working. Any errors being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

Any Eloquent query returns, by default, a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections), even for the underlying relationships. Since you are working with one, this should work:

```
$course->my_list->random();
```

This will return only one item. If you want more, you could pass an argument to the `random()` method specifying the count of items you want.

For more information, check the [documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-random)

Answer (score 1):

If you still wanna do this with your approach, can you try get_object_vars function to cast object into array.

```
$array = get_object_vars($object);
```

so that you can use them as an array in array_rand.

You might get an error, hence that it's an multi-dimensional array. Let me know so i may update.

Update for multidimensional:

Please refer to this.

// The second parameter of json_decode forces parsing into an associative array

$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
$course = Course::where('id', 1)
   ->with(['my_list' => function($query) {
       $query->inRandomOrder()->first();
   }])->first();
return $course->my_list;
```

this method is more efficient since you will only get 1 row from `my_list` not like when you use `$course->my_list->random()` which retrieves all data and from there select a random row.

Answer (score 1):

This `Object` is a Laravel collection. Please refer to the collection documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-random

You can try `$course->my_list->random()`

Comment: This is also the answer of Mr. @Mozammil, tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$course = Course::where('id', 1)
   ->with(['my_list' => function($query) {
       $query->inRandomOrder();
}])->first();
return $course->my_list;
```

Comment: It returns all the row in the `my_list`, anyway I added `->first();` in the `$query->inRandomOrder()->first()`, and working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$random_list = $course['my_list']->random(number);
```

ps: number = number of element you want to get ,